# Finding a value of a variant in a permutation equation

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a math problem that I can't solve: I don't know how to find the value of n so that

```
365! / ((365-n)! * 365^n) = 50%.
```

I am using the Casio 500ms scientific calculator but I don't know how.

Sorry because my question is too easy, I am changing my career so I have to review and upgrade my math, the subject that I have neglected for years.

Comment: This looks like the birthday problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: This problem has no solution. The value for `n = 22` is above `0.5` and for `n = 23` it's below `0.5` (assuming that `n` has to be integer).

Answer (score 2):

One COULD in theory use a root-finding scheme like Newton's method, IF you could take derivatives. But this function is defined only on the integers, since it uses factorials.

One way out is to recognize the identity

```
n! = gamma(n+1)
```

which will effectively allow you to extend the function onto the real line. The gamma function is defined on the positive real line, though it does have singularities at the negative integers. And of course, you still need the derivative of this expression, which can be done since gamma is differentiable.

By the way, a danger with methods like Newton's method on problems like this is it may still diverge into the negative real line. Choose poor starting values, and you may get garbage out. (I've not looked carefully at the shape of this function, so I won't claim for what set of starting values it will diverge on you.)

Is it worth jumping through the above set of hoops? Of course not. A better choice than Newton's method might be something like Brent's algorithm, or a secant method, which here will not require you to compute the derivative. But even that is a waste of effort.

Recognizing that this is indeed a problem on the integers, one could use a tool like bisection to resolve the solution extremely efficiently. It never requires derivatives, and it will work nicely enough on the integers. Once you have resolved the interval to be as short as possible, the algorithm will terminate, and take vary few function evaluations in the process.

Finally, be careful with this function, as it does involve some rather large factorials, which could easily overflow many tools to evaluate the factorial. For example, in MATLAB, if I did try to evaluate factorial(365):

```
factorial(365)
ans =
   Inf
```

I get an overflow. I would need to move into a tool like the symbolic toolbox, or my own suite of variable precision integer tools. Alternatively, one could recognize that many of the terms in these factorials will cancel out, so that

```
365! / (365 - n)! = 365*(365-1)*(365-2)*...*(365-n+1)
```

The point is, we get an overflow for such a large value if we are not careful. If you have a tool that will not overflow, then use it, and use bisection as I suggested. Here, using the symbolic toolbox in MATLAB, I get a solution using only 7 function evaluations.

```
f = @(n) vpa(factorial(sym(365))/(factorial(sym(365 - n))*365^sym(n)));

f(0)
ans =
1.0

f(365)
ans =
1.4549552156187034033714015903853e-157

f(182)
ans =
0.00000000000000000000000095339164972764493041114884521295

f(91)
ans =
0.000004634800180846641815683109605743

f(45)
ans =
0.059024100534225072005461014516788

f(22)
ans =
0.52430469233744993108665513602619

f(23)
ans =
0.49270276567601459277458277166297
```

Or, if you can't take an option like that, but do have a tool that can evaluate the log of the gamma function, AND you have a rootfinder available as MATLAB does...

```
f = @(n) exp(gammaln(365+1) - gammaln(365-n + 1) - n*log(365));
fzero(@(n) f(n) - .5,10)
ans =
   22.7677
```

As you can see here, I used the identity relating gamma and the factorial function, then used the log of the gamma function, in MATLAB, gammaln. Once all the dirty work was done, then I exponentiated the entire mess, which will be a reasonable number. Fzero tells us that the cross-over occurs between 22 and 23.

Answer (score 1):

If a numerical approximation is ok, ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+365%21+%2F+%28%28365-n%29%21+%2a+365%5En%29+%3D+0.5+for+n):

n ~= -22.2298272...

n ~= 22.7676903...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have some special reason for wanting an actual algorithm, even though you only have one specific problem to solve.

You're looking for a value n where...

```
365! / ((365-n)! * 365^n) = 0.5
```

And therefore...

```
(365! / ((365-n)! * 365^n)) - 0.5 = 0.0
```

The general form of the problem is to find a value `x` such that `f(x)=0`. One classic algorithm for this kind of thing is the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

[**EDIT** - as woodchips points out in the comment, the factorial is an integer-only function. My defence - for some problems (the birthday problem among them) it's common to generalise using approximation functions. I remember the [Stirling approximation of factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) being used for the birthday problem - according to [this](http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/NEWS4/BIRTHDAY.HTM#ppearsonF4y5B1.Jyv@netcom.com), Knuth uses it. The [Wikipedia page](http://crppit.epfl.ch/documentation/Hash_Function/WiKi/Birthday_problem.htm#Approximations) for the Birthday problem mentions several approximations that generalise to non-integer values.

It's certainly bad that I didn't think to mention this when I first wrote this answer.]

One problem with that is that you need the derivative of that function. That's more a mathematics issue, though you can estimate the derivative at any point by taking values a short distance either side.

You can also look at this as an optimisation problem. The general form of optimisation problems is to find a value `x` such that `f(x)` is maximised/minimised. In your case, you could define your function as...

```
f(x)=((365! / ((365-n)! * 365^n)) - 0.5)^2
```

Because of the squaring, the result can never be negative, so try to minimise. Whatever value of `x` gets you the smallest `f(x)` will also give you the result you want.

There isn't so much an algorithm for optimisation problems as a whole field - the method you use depends on the complexity of your function. However, this case should be simple so long as your language can cope with big numbers. Probably the simplest optimisation algorithm is called [hill-climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), though in this case it should probably be called rolling-down-the-hill. And as luck would have it, Newton-Raphson *is* a hill-climbing method (or very close to being one - there may be some small technicality that I don't remember).

[**EDIT** as mentioned above, this won't work if you need an integer solution for the problem as actually stated (rather than a real-valued approximation). Optimisation in the integer domain is one of those awkward issues that helps make optimisation a field in itself. The [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) is common for complex functions. However, in this case hill-climbing still works. In principle, you can even still use a tweaked version of Newton-Raphson - you just have to do some rounding and check that you don't keep rounding back to the same place you started if your moves are small.]

Comment: -1, since Newton-Raphson does not apply to factorials, which are only defined on the integers.

Comment: @woodchips - the standard fix for that is to use [Stirlings approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), though admittedly it's only a good approximation for large factorials. I assume that's how Wolfram Alpha gives a solution, as suggested by hexist.

Comment: No, the standard solution is NOT to use Stirling's approximation. The standard solution, had you suggested it, would be to use the identity relating gamma(n+1) to n!, which I pointed out in my own answer. But it seems silly to use an approximation that will not be accurate for some values of n, especially when a non-approximation is available. As far as Wolfram solving it, one would presume it MIGHT have used that same identity.

Comment: The Gamma function is a pain to compute. [Karatsuba](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/129796/510) published an algorithm in 2000, which I only found out about checking facts just now. Other than that, one common approach was - ahem - to use the [Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Stirling.27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) (admittedly a different formula, but you see my confusion?)

Comment: No, it is not a problem to compute gamma. There are implementations to be found in almost any language you will work in. Move out of the past.